# Native Base spinner not working

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am trying to show a spinner on press of button in react-native, native-base after username is entered. It is not working. Here are my steps and  code:

Steps:

1. set loading true in constructor
2. set loading false after fetching data
3. if loading true render spinner else load other screen.

   ```
   constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {
       loading: true,  
   }
   handleLoginPressed = async () => {

   //some code

        let resp = await tryAsk(this.state.sampleQuestion, this.state.username);
        this.setState({            
                 loading: false
             });

   }

   render() {
   if (this.state.fontsAreLoaded == true) {
     if (this.state.isLoggedIn === true) {
       if (this.state.loading === true){
         <View><Spinner /></View>
       }else{   
       return (
         <Somescreen/>
       );
     }    
   }
   ```

Comment: is this code written inside componentDidMount
`let resp = await tryAsk(this.state.sampleQuestion, this.state.username);
    this.setState({            
              loading: false
          });` ?

Comment: Also try just adding a plain spinner <View><Spinner /></View> to see if that works

Comment: no the code is written in function called on button press

Comment: tried <View><Spinner /></View> it did not wrk

Comment: ok <View><Spinner /></View> works for me. the problem may not be with spinner but somewhere else. i checked with the latest native-base version

Comment: please share the whole relevant code. and native-base version and react-version you are on.

Comment: react-native: 0.50.3
native base :2.3.5

Comment: a proper formatting would also help

Comment: Thx.I was able to use nativebase spinner and my code is working now,but how to disable other controls when it spins

Comment: issue solved.I was able to disable controls on spinner

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me
This is with NativeBase 2.3.6

```
<Content>
  <Spinner />
  <Spinner color="red" />
  <Spinner color="green" />
  <Spinner color="blue" />
</Content>
```

Works with `<View>` as well

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you forget `return`

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
    loading: true,  
}
handleLoginPressed = async () => {

//some code

     let resp = await tryAsk(this.state.sampleQuestion, this.state.username);
     this.setState({            
              loading: false
          });

}

render() {
if (this.state.fontsAreLoaded == true) {
  if (this.state.isLoggedIn === true) {
    if (this.state.loading === true){
      return <Spinner />
    }else{   
    return (
      <Somescreen/>
    );
  }    
}
```